# Open a SQLite file and read it with `openDatabase`

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I tried to open a new database like that :

```
localFileName = 'open-streets-dc.mbtiles';
db = window.openDatabase(localFileName, '1', 'my', 1024 * 1024 * 100);
```

It will create a new db in Web SQL and I can browse on it with chrome. In my case, I have to read an exisiting SQLite file but I did not found the solution.

I tried [sql.js](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/) but I need to make it works with an Android, with [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) and it does not work as you can see in [this issue](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/issues/90).

Do you have an idea of solution?

Answer (score 0):

I use this plugin for accessing databases with cordova. In the README you can find some helpful code.

[Cordova-SQLitePlugin](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin#opening-a-database)

Regards,

Comment: It seems to be difficult to use with ionic. Ionic mock the file `cordova.js` in development so the plugin does not work.

Comment: @Dougui I do not think ionic and this plugin do not work good together. As you can see in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237833/ionic-prepopulated-database-with-antair-cordova-sqliteplugin-help-request) you can install it with ionic.

Comment: I'm back to the original problem. The solution in the post use `window.openDatabase`. In dev mod, the database is empty and I cannot read it from a file.

Answer (score -1):

```
var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "MyDB", 200000);
    if(db) {
        console.log("database created / opened");
        //div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<hr>database created / opened";
    }
```

Comment: This code will not resolve the problem because it will not read a local file.

Comment: try it i myself is using same code and it runs well with it

Answer (score -1):

if you want access the database from chrome it's mean the database is in web server right? my be this is can help you https://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/ glad to hepl you

Comment: The database is not on the webserver. It have to be available off line.