# Visual Studio Cordova load prepopulated database

Tags: android, ios, database, visual-studio-2010, cordova

I want to program a multi platform app using cordova in visual studio; I need to use a prepopulated database but I cannot understand how to do. I tried to use litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage with no result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It will help, if you can mention exact issue, you are facing. Assuming that, you are just starting with sqllite plugin, you can view similar question here - [Ionic Prepopulated Database with Antair Cordova SQLitePlugin [help request]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237833/ionic-prepopulated-database-with-antair-cordova-sqliteplugin-help-request?rq=1)

You can create the sqllite database file and import using SQLLite plugin.

window.sqlitePlugin.importPrepopulatedDatabase({file: "mydb.sqlite", "importIfExists": true});
    db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "mydb.sqlite"});

Answer (score 0):

To open prepopulated db in cordova project, you need to do 3 steps:

1. Copy .db file into main www directory
2. Install [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-dbcopy) plugin and use copy method(this will copy the .db file to the specified directory for your os/device)
3. Use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-sqlite-storage) plugin to open the .db file

Thats it... :)